# Rails 3 multiple has_and_belongs_to_many relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, has-many-through, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm creating a rails app that contains lists. Lists are made up of:

- List_Source (e.g. National Geographic)
- List_Elements (e.g. Tanzania)
- List_Tags (e.g. Travel)

A list has a single source, multiple elements, and multiple tags. A source has multiple lists. A tag is used for multiple lists.

I have models/tables for lists, sources, list_elements, and tags. How should I organize the tables so that I can pull into one master table of lists the source, elements, and tags?

Answer (score 0):

Railscast has the answer here. Basically you create a new model (e.g. Listable) and then use has_many_through for each of the other models to create this many to many relationship.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many